# Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I'm writing console WCF-client for one WCF-WebService. When calling the service I get an error in deserializing body of request:

> Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetProfiles'

Agent Code:

```
string  userLogin = "root", userPassword = "root";
string ipaddress = "192.168.137.164";

HttpTransportBindingElement httpTransportBindingElement = new    HttpTransportBindingElement();
httpTransportBindingElement.AuthenticationScheme = AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
httpTransportBindingElement.KeepAliveEnabled = false;
httpTransportBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
httpTransportBindingElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
httpTransportBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;

TextMessageEncodingBindingElement textMessageEncodingBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
textMessageEncodingBindingElement.MaxReadPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
textMessageEncodingBindingElement.MaxWritePoolSize = int.MaxValue;
textMessageEncodingBindingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 64;
textMessageEncodingBindingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = int.MaxValue;
textMessageEncodingBindingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = int.MaxValue;
textMessageEncodingBindingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = int.MaxValue;
textMessageEncodingBindingElement.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;


CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding(textMessageEncodingBindingElement, httpTransportBindingElement);

EndpointAddress MediaEndPointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://" + ipaddress + ":80/onvif/services");

MediaClient mediaClient = new MediaClient(binding, MediaEndPointAddress);
mediaClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = userLogin;
mediaClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = userPassword;

Profile[] profiles = mediaClient.GetProfiles(); // throw excpetion
```

I have already watched the requests and responses with a sniffer and it's OK! The WebService has sent '200 OK'. If I have a small response from the WebService, there won't be any errors and exceptions! I haven't got WebService code. What should I do?

Stack trace:

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent">
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system">
<EventID>131075</EventID>
<Type>3</Type>
<SubType Name="Error">0</SubType>
<Level>2</Level>
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2012-01-11T11:11:12.2185609Z" />
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel" />
<Correlation ActivityID="{550193ea-8569-40e6-b794-1a0eed69a1ba}" />
<Execution ProcessName="TestingConsole.vshost" ProcessID="6128" ThreadID="9" />
<Channel />
<Computer>WS-LSH</Computer>
</System>
<ApplicationData>
<TraceData>
<DataItem>
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord"    Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>TestingConsole.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
<Exception>
<ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetProfiles'.    </Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeReply(Message message, Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ProxyOperationRuntime.AfterReply(ProxyRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
at TestingConsole.Onvif.Media.Media.GetProfiles(GetProfilesRequest request)
at TestingConsole.Onvif.Media.MediaClient.TestingConsole.Onvif.Media.Media.GetProfiles(GetProfilesRequest request)
at TestingConsole.Onvif.Media.MediaClient.GetProfiles()
at TestingConsole.Program.Main(String[] args)
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: Error in deserializing body of reply message for operation 'GetProfiles'. ---&gt; System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 6287). ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: The byte 0x03 is not valid at this location.  Line 2, position 6287.
    at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowInvalidXml(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Byte b)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadString(Int32 maxStringContentLength)
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadString()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadElementString()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read59_VideoSourceConfiguration(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read150_Profile(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read224_GetProfilesResponse()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer73.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>There is an error in XML document (2, 6287).</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
at     System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (2, 6287). ---&gt; System.Xml.XmlException: The byte 0x03 is not valid at this location.  Line 2, position 6287.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowInvalidXml(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Byte b)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadString(Int32 maxStringContentLength)
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadString()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadElementString()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read59_VideoSourceConfiguration(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read150_Profile(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read224_GetProfilesResponse()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer73.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.XmlSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, XmlSerializer serializer, MessagePartDescription returnPart, MessagePartDescriptionCollection bodyParts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)</ExceptionString>
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.Xml.XmlException, System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>The byte 0x03 is not valid at this location.  Line 2, position 6287.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String     res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowInvalidXml(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Byte b)
at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadString(Int32 maxStringContentLength)
at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadString()
at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadElementString()
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read59_VideoSourceConfiguration(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read150_Profile(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read224_GetProfilesResponse()
at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer73.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.Xml.XmlException: The byte 0x03 is not valid at this location.  Line 2, position 6287.
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowXmlException(XmlDictionaryReader reader, String res, String arg1, String arg2, String arg3)
   at System.Xml.XmlExceptionHelper.ThrowInvalidXml(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Byte b)
   at System.Xml.XmlUTF8TextReader.Read()
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadString(Int32 maxStringContentLength)
   at System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReader.ReadString()
   at System.Xml.XmlBaseReader.ReadElementString()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read59_VideoSourceConfiguration(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read150_Profile(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMedia.Read224_GetProfilesResponse()
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer73.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader reader)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)</ExceptionString>
</InnerException>
</InnerException>
</Exception>
</TraceRecord>
</DataItem>
</TraceData>
</ApplicationData>
```

I rewrite my code. Now I have got:

```
    string soapRequest = "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\">" +
                                 "<s:Header>" +
                                 "</s:Header>" +
                                 "<s:Body xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">" +
                                 "<GetProfiles xmlns=\"http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl\"/>" +
                                 "</s:Body>" +
                                 "</s:Envelope>";


XmlReader envelopeReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(soapRequest));

Message requestMsg = Message.CreateMessage(envelopeReader, int.MaxValue, MessageVersion.Soap12);

Message responseMsg = null;

IChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> channelFactory = binding.BuildChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>();
channelFactory.Open();

IRequestChannel channel = channelFactory.CreateChannel(MediaEndPointAddress);
channel.Open();

responseMsg = channel.Request(requestMsg);
Console.WriteLine(responseMsg.ToString());
```

The last string return message "Error reading body: System.Xml.XmlException: '�' contains invalid UTF8 bytes. ...}".

WebService sends non-ut8 bytes, but points "UTF-8" in header.
What can I do?

Reply Message Body

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: gSOAP/2.7
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 11591
Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"                         xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                       xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"                        xmlns:wsa5="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"                       xmlns:xmime5="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime"                        xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"                        xmlns:ter="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/error"                        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"                      xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"                      xmlns:c14n="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"                        xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"                       xmlns:tns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/topics"                      xmlns:ns1="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/analytics/wsdl"                       xmlns:ns2="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema"                       xmlns:ns3="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2"                      xmlns:ns4="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/bf-2"                        xmlns:ns5="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1"                      xmlns:ns6="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl"                      xmlns:ns7="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl"                      xmlns:ns9="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsrf/r-2"                         xmlns:ns10="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/imaging/wsdl"                        xmlns:ns11="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/media/wsdl"                      xmlns:ns12="http://www.onvif.org/ver20/ptz/wsdl"                        xmlns:ns13="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl/"                       xmlns:ns14="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/04/discovery"                        xmlns:ns16="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/analytics/wsdl/RuleEngineBinding"                        xmlns:ns17="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/analytics/wsdl/AnalyticsEngineBinding"                       xmlns:ns18="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointSubscriptionBinding"                        xmlns:ns19="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/EventBinding"                        xmlns:ns20="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/SubscriptionManagerBinding"                      xmlns:ns21="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/NotificationProducerBinding"                         xmlns:ns22="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/NotificationConsumerBinding"                         xmlns:ns23="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PullPointBinding"                        xmlns:ns24="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/CreatePullPointBinding"                      xmlns:ns25="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/PausableSubscriptionManagerBinding"                      xmlns:ns26="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl/RemoteDiscoveryBinding"                         xmlns:ns27="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/network/wsdl/DiscoveryLookupBinding"                         xmlns:ns28="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/events/wsdl/EventPortType"                       xmlns:ns29="http://www.3svision.com.tw/2009/event/topics">                      <SOAP-ENV:Header></SOAP-ENV:Header><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns11:GetProfilesResponse><ns11:Profiles token="Main_h264" fixed="true"><ns2:Name>Main h264</ns2:Name><ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken><Bounds xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" height="720" width="1280" y="0" x="0"></Bounds></ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration><ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken></ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration><ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration token="Main_h264"><ns2:Name>Main h264</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>H264</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Resolution><ns2:Width>1280</ns2:Width><ns2:Height>720</ns2:Height></ns2:Resolution><ns2:Quality>60</ns2:Quality><ns2:RateControl><ns2:FrameRateLimit>30</ns2:FrameRateLimit><ns2:EncodingInterval>15</ns2:EncodingInterval><ns2:BitrateLimit>3072</ns2:BitrateLimit></ns2:RateControl><ns2:H264><ns2:GovLength>0</ns2:GovLength><ns2:H264Profile>Baseline</ns2:H264Profile></ns2:H264><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration><ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>G7Ю11</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Bitrate>64000</ns2:Bitrate><ns2:SampleRate>8000</ns2:SampleRate><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration></ns11:Profiles><ns11:Profiles token="Sub_h264" fixed="true"><ns2:Name>Sub h264</ns2:Name><ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration token="1"><ns2:Name>user1</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken><Bounds xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" height="720" width="1280" y="0" x="0"></Bounds></ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration><ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken></ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration><ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration token="Sub_h264"><ns2:Name>Sub h264</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>H264</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Resolution><ns2:Width>640</ns2:Width><ns2:Height>352</ns2:Height></ns2:Resolution><ns2:Quality>70</ns2:Quality><ns2:RateControl><ns2:FrameRateLimit>30</ns2:FrameRateLimit><ns2:EncodingInterval>15</ns2:EncodingInterval><ns2:BitrateLimit>3072</ns2:BitrateLimit></ns2:RateControl><ns2:H264><ns2:GovLength>0</ns2:GovLength><ns2:H264Profile>Baseline</ns2:H264Profile></ns2:H264><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration><ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>G711</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Bitrate>64000</ns2:Bitrate><ns2:SampleRate>8000</ns2:SampleRate><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration></ns11:Profiles><ns11:Profiles token="Motion_jpeg" fixed="true"><ns2:Name>Motion jpeg</ns2:Name><ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration token="2"><ns2:Name>user2</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken><Bounds xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" height="720" width="1280" y="0" x="0"></Bounds></ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration><ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken></ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration><ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration token="Motion_jpeg"><ns2:Name>Motion jpeg</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>JPEG</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Resolution><ns2:Width>1280</ns2:Width><ns2:Height>720</ns2:Height></ns2:Resolution><ns2:QualitЭy>70</ns2:Quality><ns2:RateControl><ns2:FrameRateLimit>15</ns2:FrameRateLimit><ns2:EncodingInterval>15</ns2:EncodingInterval><ns2:BitrateLimit>3072</ns2:BitrateLimit></ns2:RateControl><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration><ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>G711</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Bitrate>64000</ns2:Bitrate><ns2:SampleRate>8000</ns2:SampleRate><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration></ns11:Profiles><ns11:Profiles token="mc_test" fixed="false"><ns2:Name>mc_test</ns2:Name><ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration token="2"><ns2:Name>Hе</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken><Bounds xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" height="720" width="1280" y="0" x="0"></Bounds></ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration><ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken></ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration><ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration token="Motion_jpeg"><ns2:Name>јч
@јч
@peg</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>JPEG</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Resolution><ns2:Width>1280</ns2:Width><ns2:Height>720</ns2:Height></ns2:Resolution><ns2:Quality>70</ns2:Quality><ns2:RateControl><ns2:FrameRateLimit>15</ns2:FrameRateLimit><ns2:EncodingInterval>15</ns2:EncodingInterval><ns2:BitrateLimit>3072</ns2:BitrateLimit></ns2:RateControl><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration><ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>G711</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Bitrate>64000</ns2:Bitrate><ns2:SampleRate>8000</ns2:SampleRate><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration></ns11:Profiles><ns11:Profiles token="MACROSCOP" fixed="false"><ns2:Name>MACROSCOP</ns2:Name><ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration token="2"><ns2:Name>Hе</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken><Bounds xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/schema" heightЮ="720" width="1280" y="0" x="0"></Bounds></ns2:VideoSourceConfiguration><ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:SourceToken>0</ns2:SourceToken></ns2:AudioSourceConfiguration><ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration token="Motion_jpeg"><ns2:Name>јч
@јч
@peg</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>JPEG</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Resolution><ns2:Width>1280</ns2:Width><ns2:Height>720</ns2:Height></ns2:Resolution><ns2:Quality>70</ns2:Quality><ns2:RateControl><ns2:FrameRateLimit>15</ns2:FrameRateLimit><ns2:EncodingInterval>15</ns2:EncodingInterval><ns2:BitrateLimit>3072</ns2:BitrateLimit></ns2:RateControl><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:VideoEncoderConfiguration><ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration token="0"><ns2:Name>user0</ns2:Name><ns2:UseCount>0</ns2:UseCount><ns2:Encoding>G711</ns2:Encoding><ns2:Bitrate>64000</ns2:Bitrate><ns2:SampleRate>8000</ns2:SampleRate><ns2:Multicast><ns2:Address><ns2:Type>IPv4</ns2:Type><ns2:IPv4Address>0.0.0.0</ns2:IPv4Address></ns2:Address><ns2:Port>0</ns2:Port><ns2:TTL>5</ns2:TTL><ns2:AutoStart>false</ns2:AutoStart></ns2:Multicast><ns2:SessionTimeout>PT0S</ns2:SessionTimeout></ns2:AudioEncoderConfiguration></ns11:Profiles></ns11:GetProfilesResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Add a tag to your question for WCF, you'll get more people reading it that way. Good luck fixing your problem.

Comment: Can you provide complete error information, stacktrace, inner exception etc?

Comment: If the response from the web serivce is 200 OK in your sniffer and is failing in your client with the above exception then its worth trying to update your proxy. There might be a situation that the wsdl has changed and the response object being recieved is not in teh expected format on your client side.

Comment: Reply from WebService has wrong (non-utf8) bytes. What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

At first, if Profile class is yourth, check the contract of your Profile object - maybe it hasn't well-configured DataContract attributes. If you have dll with Profile class, provided by the service owner, maybe it is of wrong version. YOu can try enabling [WCF trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and compare caught XML with contract of Profile object (use [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) or any other decompiler to get class code from dll)

Answer (score 0):

If the response from the web serivce is 200 OK in your sniffer and is failing in your client with the above exception then its worth trying to update your proxy. There might be a situation that the wsdl has changed and the response object being recieved is not in teh expected format on your client side

Comment: Try to take the raw response from your sniffer and try to deserialize it to the object in your proxy class. If that succeeds then there might be a configuration issue somewhere in your code.